# Node.js and zmq

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

I have a strange issue with a basic pubsub application with node and zmq:

a client is publishing strings to a broker, the problem is that the broker only receives the first line. At network level I've noticed that only the first message is sent then the next calls to .send() function have no effect (no packets are sent) so I suppose the problem is in the client/publisher.
I used the example code provided in the official guide which works perfectly, the only difference in my code is that I use prototype to have a reusable structure.
(I didn't paste subscriber's code because is not relevant and took some other not relevant stuff out)

relevant part of the client/publisher:

```
Publisher = function(zmq, pport) {
    this.logread = spawn('tail', ['-n0', '-f', '/var/log/auth.log']);
    this.publisher = zmq.socket('req');
    this.pport = pport;
};

Publisher.prototype.start = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.publisher.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:' + this.pport);
    this.logread.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        self.publisher.send(data.toString());
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
};
```

relevant part of the broker:

```
Broker = function(zmq, bpport, bsport) {
    this.server = zmq.socket('rep');
    this.bpport = bpport;
    this.bsport = bsport;
};

Broker.prototype.start = function() {
    this.server.on('message', function(request) {
        console.log(request.toString());
    });

    this.server.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:' + this.bsport, function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about publish subscribe pattern, but in your code, you create a `req` socket, and in the broker a `rep` socket, which is for the request-reply pattern. The request-reply pattern is strictly need to send first, than receive, see the [api docs](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-socket) docs, or read more from the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall)

I suppose you should use `pub` socket on the client side, and a `sub` socket on the other side, but don't know what do you want to achieve, maybe a different pattern would fit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

so I'll answer my question:
the server must send a reply to the client, until then the client will not send more messages

```
server.send('OK');
```

I also suppose there is a different way to achieve this